# How to avoid the active form to be moved to the back when reaching a breakpoint in access-vba?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, z-order

There are several non-modal forms in ms-access open layered above each other (with a small offset). Every time my VBA program reaches a breakpoint, a stop command or an error the active form is moved to the background (at the end of the Z-order).

I searched the options for a solution for this but did not find anything.

Why is the active form moved to the back and how can I avoid this strange behavior?

Comment: Is what it is. Don't think this behavior can be altered.

Comment: Writing a whole new program outside of access that detects this issue would probably be your sole solution here..

Comment: :-( This is sad, because the behavior is really very annoying...